# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, .net-maui

I'm trying to implement a method that return files from a folder of my computer, but, this error showed for me:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path.

This is my code:

```
public List<string> GetFileName()
    {
        List<string> arquivos = new List<string>();
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Files");
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            arquivos.Add(file.Name);
        }
        return arquivos;
    }
```

I would like know if in .NET MAUI or Xamarin Forms this process for take a path external is different. Thank you since now!

Comment: what platform are you using to test - Windows, Android, iOS, etc?  Android and iOS will not know what a `C:\` drive is, and even a UWP app doesn't have free access to the file system

Comment: I'm testing on Android. So, in this case can I get files only by API?

Comment: is your use case that you need to get files from a Windows PC at runtime?  If not, what specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeap, I need to get and to list files from a Windowns PC.

Comment: Over the network, or USB, or something else?  Using which protocol?  How will the user authenticate themselves?  Using standard Windows software, or will there be a service or client running on windows to communicate with?

Comment: Actually, in this case I'll get the solution by creating a method through .net core 6 into API project and after making the app to consume it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that your path is incorrect.So you are getting the error "Could not find a part of the path".

Could you please change the code like below?

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> arquivos = new List<string>();
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData));
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles();
    }
```

Also please be aware that `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` maps to `/data/user/0/com.companyname.mauiapptest/files` locally in MAUI.

Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Alexandar, thank you so much. This fix worked for me.